# Add values to empty ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have one Model that adds extra attributes to the default User Model

```
class Perfil(models.Model):
    usuario = models.OneToOneField(User)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=140,null=True,blank=True)
    departamento = models.ForeignKey(Departamento,null=True,blank=True)
    menus = models.ManyToManyField(Menu,null=True,blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.usuario.username
```

and i have the ModelForms to create a new user

```
class UsuarioForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username","password","first_name","last_name","email","is_active",)

class PerfilForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        exclude = ("usuario",)
```

my View looks like this.

```
def nuevo_usuario(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UsuarioForm(request.POST, prefix='user')
        form2 = PerfilForm(request.POST, prefix='perfil')
        if form.is_valid() * form2.is_valid():
            menus = request.POST.getlist("perfil-menus")
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST.get("user-username",""),email=request.POST.get("user-email",""),password=request.POST.get("user-password",""))
            user.first_name = request.POST.get("user-first_name","")
            user.last_name = request.POST.get("user-last_name","")
            user.is_active = request.POST.get("user-is_active","True")
            user.save()
            perfil = Perfil()
            perfil.usuario = user
            perfil.telefono = request.POST.get("perfil-telefono","")
            perfil.departamento = Departamento.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get("perfil-departamento",""))           
            perfil.save()
            men = Menu.objects.filter(pk__in=menus)
            for m in men:
                perfil.menus.add(m)
            form = UsuarioForm(prefix='user')
            form2 = PerfilForm(prefix='perfil')
    else:
        form = UsuarioForm(prefix='user')
        form2 = PerfilForm(prefix='perfil')
    return render(request,'nuevousuario.html',locals())
```

In this method I only render the form with a simple

```
<form id="form" method="post" action=''>{% csrf_token %}
                <table>
                {{form}}
                {{form2}}
                </table>
                <p><input type="submit" value="Registrar"/></p>
            </form>
```

But **I want to fill the input values with some data to edit a user**, but not only the user, I need to edit the "Perfil" values.

NOTE: the "menus" field shows in the HTML like a  < select multiple >

Sorry for the spanish code, I am working for a Latin company.

Comment: what is your problem? you want to create form with user info for edit?

Comment: Why are you setting values on the objects straight from the POST data instead of the cleaned data from the form? Django also provides a UserCreationForm.

Comment: that is correct @HasanRamezani, I want to fill the form for edit.

Comment: I dont know how to use the UserCreationForm @Brandon, what is the difference?

Comment: The difference is that by setting the values directly from the POST data, you're bypassing all of the validation the form classes provide. Never, ever trust user-submitted data. My suggestion would be to take a look at `contrib.auth.forms`

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not exactly sure what you're asking but let's clean this up a bit.

First off, you need to be leveraging the built-in `UserCreationForm` from `django.contrib.auth.forms`. Second, **never**, ***ever*** use the data directly from the form post to hydrate a model object as this completely bypasses any cleaning of data performed by the form classes. Third, the view can be greatly simplified. I'm going to assume you're using Django 1.7:

```
# forms.py

from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Perfil

class UsarioForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ()

class PerfilForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        exclude = ('usario',)


# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import UsarioForm, PerfilForm

def nuevo_usario(request):
    usario_form = UsarioForm(request.POST or None)
    perfil_form = PerfilForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if usario_form.is_valid() and perfil_form.is_valid():
            usario = usario_form.save()
            perfil = perfil_form.save(commit=False)
            perfil.usario = usario
            perfil.save()
            perfil.save_m2m()

    return render(request, 'nuevousario.html',
        {'usario_form': usario_form, 'perfil_form': perfil_form})
```

Let the ModelForm classes do what they are designed to do - create objects from *sanitized* data. You don't have to do all of that work by hand in the view. You template code also needs some help:

```
# nuevousario.html

<form action="." method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <table>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit">Registrar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            {{ usario_form.as_table }}
            {{ perfil_form.as_table }}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Are you sure you want to use a table for this form? Is it really tabular data? Doesn't seem very semantically correct. You might consider using an ordered list: `<ol>`

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Wow... this is a huge help, I really thank you , i will make the changes, but... actually my main problem is that I dont know how to **edit a user**, i mean, how to fill the form with actual data to be modiffied and saved updating the user info. Do I need to make another view similar to this? How do I take the data from my DB and put it into the value fields of my form?

Comment: You're welcome. You can pass data to the form when you instantiate it using the `initial` keyword argument: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Comment: Editing an existing user instance is similar, but you would need to pass in the data using the `instance` argument instead.

Comment: Excelent... I've found my answer. I changed a few things in my views.py and my template... I will post it. Thanks again buddy!

Comment: There's a lot going on in this view. I would recommend breaking this up into two separate views: one to create and one to edit. Easier to see what's going on. Easier to test. Better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the comments of @Brandon i have changed my code like this.

I added two URLs, one for the empty form and the other to GET the user data

```
#urls.py

url(r'^usuarios/$','main.views.usuarios',name='usuarios'),
url(r'^usuarios/(\d+)$','main.views.usuarios',name='editar_usuario'),
```

In only one view that can handle both URLs, I look for a user_id, if there is Nothing, then I display the empty form, otherwise I get the user and profile data, and with an `instance` I put the data into the input fields

```
#views.py

def usuarios(request,id_usuario=None):
    usuarios = User.objects.all()
    #Pide información de un usuario - Ask for user Info
    if id_usuario is not None: 
        usr = User.objects.get(pk=id_usuario)
        prf = Perfil.objects.get(usuario=usr)
        usuario_form = UsuarioForm(instance=usr)
        perfil_form = PerfilForm(instance=prf)
    #El formulario está vacío para nuevo usuario -Empty User Form
    else:
        usuario_form = UsuarioForm(request.POST or None)
        perfil_form = PerfilForm(request.POST or None)
    #Botón Registrar - Register Button pressed
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Si está editando se obtiene la instancia del que quiere guardar - If edit, then gets the instance to save
        if id_usuario is not None:
            usuario_form = UsuarioForm(request.POST, instance=usr)
            perfil_form = PerfilForm(request.POST, instance=prf)
        #Finalmente guarda - Finally Saves the form
        if usuario_form.is_valid() and perfil_form.is_valid():
            usuario = usuario_form.save()
            perfil = perfil_form.save(commit=False)
            perfil.usuario = usuario
            perfil.save()
            HttpResponseRedirect('/usuarios/')
    return render(request,'usuarios.html',locals())
```

Finally I added some bootstrap/crispy into the form and make it looks better.

```
#Template usuarios.html
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Usuarios Registrados</h3>
        <ul>
        {% for usuario in usuarios %}
            <li><a class="usuario_link" href="/usuarios/{{usuario.pk}}">{{ usuario.username }} - {{ usuario.first_name }}</a></li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>No hay usuarios.</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <fieldset>
            <form id="form" method="post" action=''>{% csrf_token %}
                {{usuario_form|crispy}}
                {{perfil_form|crispy}}
                <p><input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Registrar"/></p>
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
        <a href="/usuarionuevo/"><input class="btn btn-default" type="button" value="Nuevo Usuario" /></a>    
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I hope it helps someone, I am new in python and django so, thanks again @Brandon for the fantastic counseling.

If anyone have a better answer, let me know please.